# Close context menu when mouse leaves

Tags: wpf, contextmenu

Simple question - MouseLeave event doesn't get called when mouse cursor leaves ContextMenu, why is it so? 
I would like to close ContextMenu when mouse cursor has left it.
Here is little sample:

```
<Button Content="Right-click me!" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <Button.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu MouseLeave="ContextMenu_MouseLeave">
                <MenuItem Header="Menu item 1" />
                <MenuItem Header="Menu item 2" />
                <Separator />
                <MenuItem Header="Menu item 3" />
            </ContextMenu>
        </Button.ContextMenu>
    </Button>
```

Answer (score 3):

You could handle the `MouseLeave` event for the internal `Border` element of the `ContextMenu`.

Handle the `Loaded` event of the `ContextMenu` itself, find the `Border` element in the visual tree and hook up an event handler to its `MouseLeave` event:

```
<Button Content="Right-click me!" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
    <Button.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu Loaded="ContextMenu_Loaded">
            <MenuItem Header="Menu item 1" />
            <MenuItem Header="Menu item 2" />
            <Separator />
            <MenuItem Header="Menu item 3" />
        </ContextMenu>
    </Button.ContextMenu>
</Button>
```

---

```
private void ContextMenu_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ContextMenu cm = sender as ContextMenu;
    Border border = GetChildOfType<Border>(cm);
    border.MouseLeave += Border_MouseLeave;
}

private void Border_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    //do something here...
}

private static T GetChildOfType<T>(DependencyObject depObj) where T : DependencyObject
{
    if (depObj == null)
        return null;

    for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj); i++)
    {
        var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);

        var result = (child as T) ?? GetChildOfType<T>(child);
        if (result != null)
            return result;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't `GetChildOfType` be breadth-first instead of depth-first? It *probably* won't matter in most situations, but I can think of some edge cases where depth-first could cause issues.

Comment: Well, it certainly doesn't make any difference in this case where you just want to find the first Border element :)